# I am extremely interested in doing something

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, usage

I am trying to find a phrase to explain that I am extremely interested in doing something. That means that I will do something whenever I have a chance.

For example, I've found this phrase

> I am always passionate about learning something new

Does this sentence sound good? Can I use it for my purpose?

Otherwise, please suggest any good alternative to express the idea.

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your sentence. We might be able to help you more if  you could explain more about why you thought your sentence might  not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is just fine grammatically, but whether 'passionate' is the ideal word to use depends on the precise meaning you wish to communicate to your readers.

Using 'Passionate about', 'enthralled by', 'fascinated by', 'obsessed with', or 'mesmerized by' all show strong emotional feelings about the subject.

Using 'interested in', 'attracted to', 'absorbed by', 'immersed in', and 'preoccupied with' all show a strong liking for the subject but the emotion implied is less. Possibly because you have a more intellectual feeling rather than an emotional interest in the subject.